# Error in Mysql query Insert or update

Tags: mysql

I am a little bit desesperate with this query, I can't find my fault:

```
INSERT INTO device (
                    Device_UUID, 
                    Model, 
                    Manufacturer, 
                    Latitude, 
                    Longitude, 
                    Type, 
                    Registration_Date, 
                    Status, 
                    API_Source) 
             values (
                    'WW', 
                    'a', 
                    'v', 
                    '0.00',
                    '0.00', 
                    'BUS', 
                    '2014-01-01 12:11:11', 
                    '1', 
                    'R') 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                    Model = "wwww", 
                    Manufacturer = "bbbbb", 
                    Registration_Date = "2014-01-01 12:11:11";
```

All fields are String, even latitud and longitude

Comment: Sorry I forgot, already added

Comment: Device_UUID is the primary key

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a5066/1). You are using PHP or another programming language?

Comment: You have removed the error with recent edits. Please readd them.

Answer (score 0):

Type is a keyword. Try to put Type inside some ".

Comment: I tried with " and ' and other error appears related to "